# Python 3.6.0 can't be installed on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu

I wrote a script on my Windows machine using python 3.6.0. I wanted to run it on Linux machines as well so I transferred the .py script onto my Ubuntu VM. The problem is, I tried to install python 3.6.0 in every way possible but it doesn't really work. Python3 works when I want to execute a .py file, but since I am trying to use pyisntaller to convert it into an executable for linux, I need the default version as 3.6.0. `python --version` gives me `Python 2.7.2`. How can I fix this so when I do python --version it shows 3.6.0?

Comment: Lying and yelling at us won't make people more inclined to help you.

Comment: The down votes are probably because your problem is too broad and unclear. You need to ask more specific question.

Comment: This might be better on SuperUser.

Comment: Try `python3 --version`

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in changing your default python version, Ubuntu relies heavily on older versions of python. And what do you mean by convert it into an executable for Linux? Almost every file on your file system is an executable. If you want to make your program run as a command in the terminal you can do this though:

`text_editor_of_your_choice .bashrc`

This should open the hidden .bashrc file, and scroll to the bottom of it. Below is what the file looks like...

[.bashrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C19I.png)

After that you can create a function for the python command you want to run.

eg. `function ghst {python3.6 /home/user/example_script/example.py $@}`

Start a terminal session and then try running it. Now that's if you want to run it inside the terminal. If it you want to create this "executable file" you speak of you can create a simple shell script.

First go in the terminal and run `touch file_name_of_your_choice.sh`

This will create a blank file named file_name_of_your_choice with the file extension "sh". After that open the text file in whatever directory you created it in, if you are unsure do `pwd`.

In your first line make sure that the user is inside the directory of the .py file by doing

`cd /home/user/folder/` On the next line you should then execute the .py file. You can do this by typing this: `python3 file.py`. This will execute the program inside a terminal window. After you have done all of this make sure that the python file and the script file are executable. Do this by doing `chmod +x file.py` and `chmod file.sh`.

This is what the end result looks like

[example script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNKfF.png)

You mentioned inside your question that you want your program to be able to run on Linux machines as well. Whether this is for personal or a public project of some sort it comes in handy by packaging all the required files in a `.zip` format this makes it easy to unpack everything when moving to separate machines. If there are any problems let me know.

Comment: My bad, I thought in order to save changes to the .bashrc file you needed root permissions. Turns out I was wrong.